# If it is not allowed to rollback a TRUNCATE statement then how is it possible to use it in a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate Table Within Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522931/truncate-table-within-transaction)

If it is not allowed to rollback a TRUNCATE statement then how is it rolled back in a transaction? Consider the following code:

```
USE tempdb
GO
-- Create Test Table
CREATE TABLE TruncateTest (ID INT)
INSERT INTO TruncateTest (ID)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
GO
-- Check the data before truncate
SELECT * FROM TruncateTest
GO
-- Begin Transaction
BEGIN TRAN
-- Truncate Table
TRUNCATE TABLE TruncateTest
GO
-- Check the data after truncate
SELECT * FROM TruncateTest
GO
-- Rollback Transaction
ROLLBACK TRAN
GO
-- Check the data after Rollback
SELECT * FROM TruncateTest
GO
-- Clean up
DROP TABLE TruncateTest
GO
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? In SQL Server TRUNCATE is transactional. Where did you read that it is not?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you

Comment: Once upon a time, the question was tagged with the [tag:oracle] tag as well as the [tag:sql-server] tag.  A few days after the question was asked, the [tag:oracle] tag was removed.

Answer (score 15):

It is a fairly common SQL Server belief that [Truncate Cannot Be Rolled Back Because It Is Not Logged](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/06/13/1458.aspx). However the code in your question just verifies that this is in fact a myth.

`TRUNCATE` does entail much *less* logging than `DELETE` as it only logs the page deallocatons and some metadata updates to system tables rather than recording the entire contents of the deleted rows to the log ([See a detailed breakdown of logging here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/why-use-both-truncate-and-drop/7685#7685)).

SQL Server [continues to lock](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Search-Engine-QA-10-When-are-pages-from-a-truncated-table-reused.aspx) the deallocated pages until the transaction commits preventing their re-allocation so `ROLLBACK` of a `TRUNCATE` simply needs to reverse these page deallocations and system table updates that are recorded in the log.

Answer (score 6):

## MS SQL:

The concept that a Truncate statement cannot be rolled back is fairly commonly misunderstood.

When you execute a Truncate statement, it does not get logged in the log file as it is a DDL statement.

So if you Truncate a table, you cannot Roll Back to a point in time before the truncate.

However, in a Transaction, Rollback is permitted and functions just as any other rollback would.

The rollback referred to is not transactional rollback.

In essence: Anywhere before a COMMIT is issued, you can rollback a TRUNCATE statement. After a COMMIT, you cannot rollback the data even by using the log file. Unrecoverable.

Comment: As this question is asked for Oracle and SQL Server you should add a note that your answer is only talking about SQL Server (in Oracle you cannot rollback a TRUNCATE)

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, the TRUNCATE statement terminates the current transaction before it executes (with a COMMIT, I believe).  Then, because it is treated like a DDL statement, the TRUNCATE executes without possibility of rollback.  And then a new transaction is started.

As I understand it, the behaviour of other DDL statements in Oracle is somewhat similar.

Some DBMS provide transactional DDL statements - and very useful it is, too.

Comment: thank you, can you give me any official links to refer?