# TRUNCATE in SQL Server rolls back on failure of last TRUNCATE

Tags: sql-server

I am starting a transaction and executing multiple truncate table statements but if last fails then it rolls back all truncate. I am trying to depict the same behavior on SQL Server command prompt.

I am trying to execute following SQL statements in SQL Server 2012:

```
create table pkt1(id integer)
GO

create table pkt2(id integer)
GO

insert into pkt1 values(10)
insert into pkt1 values(20)

insert into pkt2 values(10)
insert into pkt2 values(20)

select * from pkt1
```

Output:

```
id
------
10
20


select * from pkt2
```

Result:

```
id
------
10
20


begin transaction
   truncate table pkt1;
   truncate table pkt2;
   truncate table pkt3;
   commit;
```

Error:

> Msg 4701, Level 16, State 1, Server PNI6W11198, Line 4
>   Cannot find the object "pkt3" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

```
select * from pkt2
```

Output:

```
id
------
10
20

select * from pkt1
```

Output:

```
id
-----
10
20
```

`TRUNCATE` is supposed to be Transact SQL and should commit earlier truncate for pkt1 and pkt2. But it does rollback for all.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Truncate can be rolled back IF it is contained in the Transaction scope and the session is not closed.

Comment: I believe it is because the error happen before the commit. You've started a transaction block which means that nothing gets committed until commit is called. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522931/truncate-table-within-transaction

Comment: ***YES*** this is expected behavior - that is how a **transcation** works - and is supposed to work. Nothing wrong here (except possibly your expectations)

Comment: I thought being TRUNCATE a Transact SQL it would behave like a DDL and would do Auto commit after each sql execution

Answer (score 0):

Table `pkt3` does not exist so that script fails.

Your transaction brackets all three `truncate` statements : one fails - they all fail

Comment: The transaction is never even started.