# Laravel truncating table causing error during test

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-sail

I'm trying to truncate a table, but everytime I try to run it through a test I get a PDOException:
`There is no active transaction`

I'm using the `RefreshDatabase` trait.

My code looks like this:

```php
Model::query()->truncate();
```

Comment: Model::truncate()

Comment: Why are you truncating if the trait does it already for you ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have actual logic doing truncate that I'm trying to test

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you truncating a table in live code ? Why would you need to do that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the error is caused by the `truncate` action

based on the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1522974/6644975

when you execute a `truncate` statement the transaction is committed and then the TRUNCATE is executed and cannot be undone.

This affects the `RefreshDatabase` trait which uses a transaction for each and every test.

here's how it runs

1. `RefreshDatabase` creates a transactions
2. You do something here with the database
3. you execute `truncate`
4. `Truncate` commits the transaction
5. `RefreshDatabase` tries to commit a transaction but will not be able to because it's already committed causing an error `There is no active transaction`

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this makes sense. So how would one implement replacing all records in a database if truncate is not a good testing solution.

Comment: @Ezrab_ Are you using truncate to reset Incrementing ID? if NOT you can just use `DB::table('table_name')->delete();` which deletes all records in the database.

Comment: How we can prevent that? I need to reset autoincrement also

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the trait `DatabaseMigrations` instead of `RefreshDatabase`